# multirow and text wrapping

Tags: multirow, booktabs

I have a problem using `multirow` along with text wrapping when spanning cell contains a lot of text. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{@{} m{3cm} m{3cm} m{3cm} @{}} \toprule[0.04cm]
Lorem & Lorem & Lorem \\ \midrule[0.04cm] 
Lorem ipsum & \multirow{2}{3cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.} & Lorem ipsum \\ \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Lorem ipsum & & Lorem ipsum \\ \midrule
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\ \bottomrule[0.04cm]
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{@{} m{3cm} m{3cm} m{3cm} @{}} \toprule[0.04cm]
Lorem & Lorem & Lorem \\ \midrule[0.04cm] 
Lorem ipsum & \multirow{2}{3cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.} & Lorem ipsum \\ \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Lorem ipsum & & Lorem ipsum \\ \midrule
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\ \bottomrule[0.04cm]
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The only difference between these tables is the text length in multirow cell. The first table looks fine, but the second has some overlap:

[image]

Wrapping text in parbox doesn't help. Is there any universal way to set a proper height and vertical alignment for that cell? That code is a part of automatic report-generator, so text length in the spanning cell may vary.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, the best way to do that is to create a table inside a table cell instead of using rowspan, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{@{} m{3cm} m{3cm} m{3cm} @{}} \toprule[0.04cm]
Lorem & Lorem & Lorem \\ \midrule[0.04cm] 
\begin{tabular}{@{} m{3cm} @{}} Lorem ipsum \\ \cmidrule{1-1} Lorem ipsum \end{tabular} & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. & 
\begin{tabular}{@{} m{3cm} @{}} Lorem ipsum \\ \midrule Lorem ipsum \end{tabular} \\ \midrule
Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum \\ \bottomrule[0.04cm]
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]